# SPGridview single DataKeyName instead for multiple?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have a SPgridview in a webpart.

And i want to get the ID of the item, not the index, when i select a row.
How do i do that?

Normally i would just set the DataKeyName of the gridview to "ID" or whatever the column in the table is called.

But here im not allowed to set a single datakeyname, only multiple with a stringArray..
I tried setting it to a string array with only one item, but that failed.

I feed the data inside the gridview using a SPdatasource.

Im very new to this sharepoint world..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the error i get when trying to set the datakeynames using a stringarray with one item..
"Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'ID'  Key being added: 'ID'" huh?

Comment: It appears the error was caused by the gridview.databind method.
So now i am experimenting with if page is postback, but it is pretty wierd, cause' i want the fields to show up after the postback, but right now they wont. Grrrr

Comment: Okay, it was pretty simple..
I put the gridview.datakeynames = new string[] { "ID" };
inside a If !page.ispostback.

And that fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and searched 2 days for a solution. After reading this post I had the idea to check the installed updates on both servers. The server which stored the datakeynames needed the latest .NET updates. After installing .NET 3.5 SP1 the error went away!

Maybe this helps someone. ;)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the KB article. I only used the Windows Update function which updated my server to the newest version.

Comment: Yes! This solved our problem as well. Darn people refusing to install Windows updates...